# Adding a new Dll to visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, dll

I have made a new Dll to use in my C# projects and i would like to know where to put it so whenever i open a new project it will be avaiable and i wont need to use Project>Add Refrence..

Anyone have any ideas? i have looked over the net for sometime, Plus, What do i have to do so every time i open a new project it would just add it to the using list.
for example, if my dll is called Eliran it would look like this every time i open a new project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Eliran;
```

or for windows form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Eliran;
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are going to need to add a reference to use the library (or import). You can modify the project templates though to do this I believe (although I wouldn't recommend it).

Comment: you could change the project templates or create a new one, not really needed though.  you could add it to nuget and just the package manager to add it.  suggest reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx

Comment: @Mike, i dont really know how to use the nuget, can u please give me a tutorial or something?

Comment: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the default templates.  They are stored in the folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp
```

For VS2010, so it would be a little different for 2012.

You could find a project type that you want to change.  You could modify the default project you want directly or open the project template in VS then modify it.  Click export project then overwrite the default project template with the new exported template.  With this you can add the reference every time you use a template (i.e. Windows App, Class Library).  You would have to do this for each project type.

Then you want the using at the top of classes.  You would have to modify default item templates.

For VS2010 it is in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033
```

There is one named Class, and you could find the ones for windows forms, etc...

This is a lot of work, but it might be better for your situation.

Comment: it looks like it would could ruin something i really dont want to mess with the system files, ill just leave it like that and use add refrence every time :D